# Protractor running some tests in parallel and some tests sequentially

Tags: configuration, protractor

I have a situation where I want to run some protractor tests in parallel in order to save time taken to run the tests. The difficulty I have is that some of these tests can't be run in parallel as the results in 1 browser are affecting the expected results in another session.

Is it possible to set my protractor config file in order to be able to do this? My current setup is shown below but this isn't working:

multiCapabilities: [

```
 //tests run sequentially
{'browserName': 'firefox', specs: ['e2e/DynamicUpdates/**/*.spec.js'], maxInstances: 1, exclude: ['e2e/main/**/*.spec.js']},
{'browserName': 'chrome', specs: ['e2e/DynamicUpdates/**/*.spec.js'], maxInstances: 1, exclude: ['e2e/main/**/*.spec.js']},
{'browserName': 'internet explorer', specs: ['e2e/DynamicUpdates/**/*.spec.js'], maxInstances: 1, exclude: ['e2e/main/**/*.spec.js']},
{'browserName': 'safari', specs: ['e2e/DynamicUpdates/**/*.spec.js'], maxInstances: 1, exclude: ['e2e/main/**/*.spec.js']},
// Main tests - run in parallel
{'browserName': 'chrome', 'chromeOptions': {args: ['--start-maximized']}, shardTestFiles: true, maxInstances: 3},
{'browserName': 'firefox', shardTestFiles: true, maxInstances: 3}, 
{'browserName': 'safari', shardTestFiles: true, maxInstances: 3},    
{
  'browserName': 'internet explorer',
  'binary': 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe',
  'ensureCleanSession': true,
  'nativeEvents': false,
  'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true,
  'disable-popup-blocking': true,
  'enablePersistentHover': true,
  shardTestFiles: true,
  maxInstances: 3 
},      

// Performance tests (currently not run against IE due to webdriver issues)
{'browserName': 'chrome', specs: ['/**/*.spec.js'] },
{'browserName': 'firefox', specs: ['/**/*.spec.js'] },
```

],

maxSessions: 3,

Comment: You can easily do this with gulp or grunt. You can split your tests into 5 or more different groups and they will all run in parallel in the same browser and once the first group finishes with chrome it will open Firefox. Depending on how you wrote your tests there could be collisions but it won't be because they are running the same tests at the same time but in different browsers. I could provide a code sample using gulp or grunt if you are interested in this type of parallel execution of tests. What gulp or grunt give you is control of the order in which the specs run.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I have a similar problem where some tests affect the app globally and cannot be run in parallel. I saw a post here (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1421) suggesting multiple conf files.

Comment: I did manage to get around it, in the way that you suggest. I created multiple conf files, and organised my directory structure so that certain tests are run sequentially, and others in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

In the specs array, type out the files in order that you want them to run in. Or keep it the way it is and change the names of the files so they run in the proper sequence.

```
{'browserName': 'firefox',
specs: ['e2e/DynamicUpdates/folder1/testA.spec.js', 'e2e/DynamicUpdates/folder1/testB.spec.js', 'e2e/DynamicUpdates/folder1/testC.spec.js'], 
maxInstances: 1, exclude: ['e2e/main/**/*.spec.js']},
```

Comment: My problem is that if other browsers are running any other test simultaneously then it might affect the tests that I want to run sequentially (and in isolation).
I am doing some dynamic updates and I want to test these updates on different browsers, but I want no other tests running at the same time on any browser to ensure that the dynamic updates are showing correctly. ANY other tests that are running might affect the results. These are the only tests that I want to run in this manner. All other tests I would want to run in parallel to speed up the testing.

Comment: Is it possible to create a different user for each test suite that you would like to test in isolation so that they don't interfere with the same instance? Or possibly run the isolation test before or after all the others have finished.